# Select another div within a common 'root' using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this kind of structure:

```
<div class="root">
    <div class="image">
        <div class="price">$100</div>
    </div>
    <div class="productinfo">
        <div class="title" id="title1">Banana</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="root">
    <div class="image">
        <div class="price">$14</div>
    </div>
    <div class="productinfo">
        <div class="title" id="title2">Spoon</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, I need to know the width of the div with class `price` that has content `$100` and not end up getting the width of div `$14`; **but** the code need to be started from `$("#title1")`. How I'm supposed to do that? Or, how I'm supposed to select the parent of an element, and then select the child with specific class of that parent? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a more generic way which could be used if you do not know the "common" parent class:

```
$("#title1").closest(":has(.price)").find(".price")
```

Example:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".title").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(":has(.price)").find(".price").hide().fadeIn("slow");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Click on labels to highlight corresponding price</p>

<div>
  <div class="image">
    <div class="price">$100</div>
  </div>
  <div class="productinfo">
    <div class="title" id="title1">Banana</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="image">
    <div class="price">$14</div>
  </div>
  <div class="productinfo">
    <div class="title" id="title2">Spoon</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is slower than `closest('.root')`, but a good option if it happens at click speeds and you don't have a specific root class.

Comment: Correct, it is useful only in situations when there are no classes to target.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the function `closest()` for this:

```
$("#title1").closest('.root').find('.price').text();
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ns90yb5d/)

A second possibility is the use of the `parents()`-function:

```
$("#title1").parents('.root').find('.price').text();
```

[Demo 2](https://jsfiddle.net/e29rxz7r/)

**Reference**

[.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

[.parents()](https://api.jquery.com/parents/)

Comment: Oh I see. Never knew there are functions like that. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 2):

Also you can get the value using `html()`

Like this:

```
var price = $("#title1").closest('.root').find('.price').html();
alert(price);
```

Comment: It's nice to know that I can use `html()` function too for that. Thanks!